# State is not passed down to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue in figuring in what conditions props are not passed down by the tree. I have a Fetcher class in which I populate with "layouts", then pass it to children props, but I cannot access it from child component.

EX:

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react'
   import axios from "axios";

    export default class Fetcher extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        layouts: [],
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getLayouts();
}

getLayouts = () => {
    axios
        .get("/layout")
        .then((res) => {
            this.setState({
                layouts: res.data,
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};

render() {
    return (

        this.props.children(this.state.layouts)
    )
}

}
```

This is my Parent component on which I pass some props children:

ex:

```
 import React, { Fragment } from "react";
 import Fetcher from "./Fetcher";

 class App extends Component {

          <Fetcher>
            {(layouts) => {
              return <Fragment>
                <NewLayout
                  layoutsList={layouts} />
              </Fragment>
            }}
          </Fetcher>
 }







 import React from "react";



 class NewLayout extends React.Component {


 constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {

  layouts: [],
  }}

 componentDidMount() {
  this.setState(() => ({
    layouts: this.props.layoutList
  }))
 }


   render() {

  { console.log(this.state.layouts) }
  { console.log(this.props.layoutList) }


  return (
   ....
```

Comment: `this.props.children` is **not** a function, please read the docs

Answer (score 0):

The [`children` prop is not a function](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#propschildren), if you want to pass a property to it you should use [`React.Children`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) API with [`React.cloneElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement):

```
class Fetcher extends Component {
  state = {
    layouts: [/*some layout values*/],
  };

  render() {
    const children = this.props.children;
    const layouts = this.state.layouts;
    return React.Children.map(children, (child) =>
      React.cloneElement(child, { layouts })
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typo my friend, looks like you pass `layoutsList` prop to `NewLayout`, but internally use `layoutList`.